# I can't reassign a greater value in this program. (Python)

Tags: python

This is what I've done so far. It produces 2 consecutive integers that increase then, the third one is smaller and it goes in random orders.

```
import random

new_k = (random.randint(0 , 100))
k = (random.randint(0 , 100))

while k >= new_k :

    print(k)
    new_k = k
```

Comment: How are you running this? As it is, this will only print one number.

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking. Can you please reword your question? What is the problem exactly? Please explain using a concrete example, how it is failing for you.

Comment: I want to make it so when I re run it, it will produce a larger number. If i get a number 10 and its greater than the old number, (new_k), then new_k would equal the k that was larger than the previous smaller k.

Comment: I already had included import random just here it didn't show up.

Comment: So, what you are saying is that your random number being generated has to be based on what the value of `new_k` is then, right?

Comment: Are you talking about re-running the whole script? If so you'd need to write your number to a file or some other persistent storage, otherwise the script wont know what number it has to be higher than on subsequent runs.

Comment: yes re assigning the K to a larger value everytime so , it would check it and would  see that  it was larger than the previous one and try to get a random number to be greater then that.

Comment: what else would you propose then?

Comment: @Don are you talking about running your code in a loop or reloading your script many times? I'm a bit confused about what you want to do and why you want to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does reassign the greater value which happens to be `k` here to `new_k`.

I have added print statement in `if` and `else` part to print the newly assigned value to `new_k` and I ran it on IDLE and it works as programmed.

```
import random

new_k = 1
k = (random.randint(0 , 100))
if k >= new_k:
    print("Greater Use Case")
    print(k)
    new_k = k
    print(new_k)
else:
    print("Smaller Use Case")
    print(k)
    print(new_k)
```

Sample Run in IDLE

```
========= RESTART: C:/sample.py =========
Greater Use Case
9
9
>>> 
========= RESTART: C:/sample.py =========
Greater Use Case
8
8
>>> 
========= RESTART: C:/sample.py =========
Greater Use Case
55
55
>>> 
========= RESTART: C:/sample.py =========
Greater Use Case
13
13
```

`EDIT` : If you want it in increasing order then your initial code is incorrect and you would need to write an iterative structure. I am giving you a very basic implementation which you can edit as per your need but it will give you a clear idea that the value is increasing and when it decreases, it quits.

```
import random

new_k = 1
while (True):
    k = (random.randint(0 , 100))
    if k >= new_k:
        print("Greater Use Case")
        new_k = k
        print("k=" + str(k) + "; new_k=" + str(new_k) + "\n")
    else:
        ## NOTE: i quit here when it is decreasing
        print("Smaller Use Case")
        print("k=" + str(k) + "; new_k=" + str(new_k) + "\n")
        break
```

Sample Run

```
========= RESTART: C:/sample.py =========
Greater Use Case
k=83; new_k=83

Smaller Use Case
k=2; new_k=83

>>> 
========= RESTART: C:/sample.py =========
Greater Use Case
k=51; new_k=51

Greater Use Case
k=69; new_k=69

Greater Use Case
k=78; new_k=78

Smaller Use Case
k=61; new_k=78

>>> 
========= RESTART: C:/sample.py =========
Greater Use Case
k=22; new_k=22

Greater Use Case
k=100; new_k=100

Smaller Use Case
k=34; new_k=100

>>> 
========= RESTART: C:/sample.py =========
Greater Use Case
k=35; new_k=35

Smaller Use Case
k=28; new_k=35
```

Comment: it was first 70, then why did it go to 28. Shouldn't it go to a greater number like 88, then if it were 88 it would go to something greater than 88. Increasing every time.

Comment: I want it just to increase not go from 9 to 8 to 55 to 13.

Comment: for that you would need a while loop which will keep on increasing till it falsify the given condition of not being greater than k

Comment: I have added more print statements to explain you what is going on. As per your code, it will only execute once, if you need it to be increasing couple of times depending on value returned by `random` then you need to write a iterative structure like while, do while etc.

Comment: I put a while loop above edited and it just keeps printing the same value.

Comment: check my solution again, I have posted `while` loop

Comment: It prints same value as you do not regenerate the value for `k` or `new_k` inside the while loop, like I do. Check `EDIT` in my solution with while loop.

Comment: If it is acceptable answer then please accept my answer and vote up :)

Comment: yeah thats what I wanted to do. Thanks I am new to Python .

Comment: Also when using while its always the negation of what you want right?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow and Python both! `while` loop only runs when the condition is `True`, the moment condition turns `False`, it quits. Here is more for you to read when you have time  https://wiki.python.org/moin/WhileLoop